# Calculating statistics of each kdeplot contour

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

I've got a following `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd 
ex = pd.DataFrame({'x': {51963: 60.0, 52020: 110.0, 52054: 90.0, 52071: 86.0, 52072: 86.0, 52073: 86.0, 52131: 96.0, 52132: 96.0, 52140: 115.0, 52209: 92.0, 52346: 112.0, 52347: 114.0, 52429: 103.0, 52497: 104.0, 52561: 88.0, 52626: 110.0, 52627: 110.0, 52630: 109.0, 52631: 111.0, 52685: 105.0, 52725: 95.0, 52726: 95.0, 52727: 95.0, 52915: 100.0, 52916: 100.0, 52918: 101.0, 52936: 64.0, 52940: 66.0, 52987: 96.0, 52988: 96.0, 53088: 67.0, 53122: 76.0, 53123: 76.0, 53172: 105.0, 53420: 5.0, 53561: 105.0, 53585: 114.0, 53586: 114.0, 53587: 118.0, 53681: 105.0, 53927: 115.0, 53968: 117.0, 53993: 107.0, 54062: 114.0, 54063: 113.0, 54140: 103.0, 54141: 103.0, 54143: 107.0, 54145: 107.0, 54146: 107.0, 54200: 84.0, 54624: 88.0, 54625: 88.0, 54661: 116.0, 54664: 114.0, 54679: 119.0, 54685: 67.0, 54695: 59.0, 54706: 64.0, 54711: 69.0, 54722: 70.0, 54751: 100.0, 54753: 104.0, 54934: 81.0, 54960: 67.0, 55028: 107.0, 55082: 99.0, 55083: 99.0, 55084: 99.0, 55198: 102.0, 55199: 102.0, 55200: 102.0, 55279: 55.0, 55280: 55.0, 55388: 99.0, 55391: 97.0, 55392: 96.0, 55459: 97.0, 55460: 97.0, 55464: 99.0, 55465: 99.0, 55467: 97.0, 55499: 113.0, 55500: 113.0, 55501: 114.0, 55504: 107.0, 111812: 61.0, 111862: 69.0, 111863: 69.0, 111864: 68.0, 111868: 68.0, 111872: 63.0, 111971: 82.0, 111972: 82.0, 111974: 83.0, 111995: 101.0, 111996: 101.0, 111997: 102.0, 112041: 95.0, 112042: 95.0}, 'y': {51963: 41.0, 52020: 45.0, 52054: 57.0, 52071: 12.0, 52072: 12.0, 52073: 13.0, 52131: 26.0, 52132: 26.0, 52140: 34.0, 52209: 19.0, 52346: 47.0, 52347: 45.0, 52429: 39.0, 52497: 18.0, 52561: 12.0, 52626: 54.0, 52627: 54.0, 52630: 53.0, 52631: 51.0, 52685: 35.0, 52725: 37.0, 52726: 37.0, 52727: 37.0, 52915: 58.0, 52916: 58.0, 52918: 58.0, 52936: 34.0, 52940: 41.0, 52987: 52.0, 52988: 52.0, 53088: 28.0, 53122: 52.0, 53123: 52.0, 53172: 32.0, 53420: 37.0, 53561: 13.0, 53585: 28.0, 53586: 28.0, 53587: 21.0, 53681: 26.0, 53927: 38.0, 53968: 38.0, 53993: 35.0, 54062: 32.0, 54063: 31.0, 54140: 41.0, 54141: 41.0, 54143: 33.0, 54145: 36.0, 54146: 36.0, 54200: 24.0, 54624: 14.0, 54625: 14.0, 54661: 40.0, 54664: 41.0, 54679: 39.0, 54685: 43.0, 54695: 59.0, 54706: 44.0, 54711: 28.0, 54722: 18.0, 54751: 22.0, 54753: 22.0, 54934: 57.0, 54960: 51.0, 55028: 22.0, 55082: 19.0, 55083: 19.0, 55084: 19.0, 55198: 27.0, 55199: 27.0, 55200: 27.0, 55279: 44.0, 55280: 44.0, 55388: 29.0, 55391: 30.0, 55392: 33.0, 55459: 14.0, 55460: 14.0, 55464: 9.0, 55465: 9.0, 55467: 10.0, 55499: 11.0, 55500: 11.0, 55501: 8.0, 55504: 14.0, 111812: 40.0, 111862: 24.0, 111863: 24.0, 111864: 21.0, 111868: 23.0, 111872: 5.0, 111971: 18.0, 111972: 18.0, 111974: 16.0, 111995: 14.0, 111996: 14.0, 111997: 12.0, 112041: 15.0, 112042: 15.0}})
```

For this `DataFrame` I can plot density using `sns.kdeplot()` as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.kdeplot(df.x, df.y, cmap = 'Reds')
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
```

[image]

From what I observed, on default, there are 10 contours on `sns.kdeplot()`, meaning that data is binned into 11 bins, with contours dividing bins with different densities. Let's say I want to take the 3rd contour, counting from the most outside one, and calculate various statistics for it - e.g. area  enclosed by this contour, horizontal or vertical range etc.. How can I do that? In other words, how can I calculate 2-dimensional kde, and then calculate the area for which kde is greater than, for example, 0.2?

Comment: In principle you could get the contour data from `ax.collections[0].collections[2]` and apply [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to obtain the area.

Comment: note that KDE's don't "bin" data like histograms do, it stands for "kernel density estimate" and are a nice non-parametric way of smoothing data.  seaborn's `kdeplot` uses [scipy's `gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to do the heavy lifting and then uses matplotlib's [`contour`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) to actually calculate/draw the contours

Comment: Yeah, but contour plots show the data so that every two adjacent contours are equidistant with respect to 3rd (hidden) dimension, right? Therefore, I thought that I could use nth contour as a way of saying that inside that contour density is greater than x, therefore area of density greater than x is equal to area of that contour. And everything outside that contour can be treated as sort of outlier as it has a low probability to occur outside the contour.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't mind using a finite approximation to this (this is probably better than getting contour data from matplotlib) you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps

# estimate kernel density of data
kde = sps.gaussian_kde(ex.values.T)

# get a regular grid of points over our region of interest
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, 130, 500),
    np.linspace(0, 70, 500))

# calculate probability density on these points
z = kde.pdf([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)

# note, the above calls are identical to how seaborn does things

# proportion of points above the 30%, i.e. approx the third contour line
zi = z > np.max(z) * 0.3

# print some summaries
print('x = (%.1f, %.1f)' % (min(xx[zi]), max(xx[zi])))
print('y = (%.1f, %.1f)' % (min(yy[zi]), max(yy[zi])))
print('area = %.1f' % (130 * 70 * np.mean(zi)))
```

which gives me:

```
x = (57.1, 124.3)
y = (3.4, 59.2)
area = 2154.8
```

you can see what seaborn currently does by searching for "bivariate" in [distributions.py](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/distributions.py) (e.g. functions [`_bivariate_kdeplot`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/c73055b2a9d9830c6fbbace07127c370389d04dd/seaborn/distributions.py#L472) and [`_scipy_bivariate_kde`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/c73055b2a9d9830c6fbbace07127c370389d04dd/seaborn/distributions.py#L385)).  the reason I say this is "better" than getting contour data from matplotlib is because I'm basically doing the same thing, just with a higher resolution grid (the above samples it 25 times as much).

the summaries should mostly be obvious, except maybe the "area" one which is like a [monte-carlo estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) (that page animates a demo calculating pi) except we're sampling on a regular grid so the error will be much smaller.

the estimates above will be approximate, `x` is accurate to nearest `130 / 500 = 0.26`, and `y` is `0.14`.  the area is accurate to almost 4 significant figures; I get a standard deviation of 0.30 and 95% CI of (2154.3, 2155.4).  if you figure out how to calculate this using contours from matplotlib it would be great if you posted it so I could compare and see which is actually "better".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really get what you did here. Could you elaborate on your answer? And, first and foremost - why do you think this is better than getting exact contour from matplotlib?

Comment: @jakes matplotlib doesn't get "exact" contours, they're calculated from a finite set of samples of the density so will have associated errors...  the algorithm it uses should interpolate between samples, so it's potentially more accurate but it would be interesting to actually see